# SwiftUI Menu Picker Navigation Bar show only icon

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios14

I want to have a menu picker on the navigation bar, so far I was able to accomplish that with the following code

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing, content: {
        Picker(selection: $requestHistoryFilter, content: {
            ForEach(SongRequestsContainer.SongHistoryFilter.allCases, id: \.self) {
                Text($0.displayText())
            }
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
        })                          
})
```

But the code above always outputs the text of the selected option on the navigation bar, what I wanted was to always show the label, is there a way of accomplish that?

In this case was I would like to show always the image.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Try using a Menu here instead of a picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @hayesk suggestion, wrapping using the Menu is the way to go

Here's what worked for me as reference for others

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing, content: {
        Menu(content: {
            Picker(selection: $requestHistoryFilter, label: Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")) {
                ForEach(VideoRequestsContainer.VideoHistoryFilter.allCases, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.displayText())
                }
            }
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
        })
     })
}
```